# NestedScrollView with 5 multiple recyclerview dont show any value

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**This is my code for the `RecyclerViews` Page:**

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private RecyclerView firstRecyclerView;

     JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

     RequestQueue requestQueue;


     NestedScrollView nsv;

     private ArrayList<Recipes>GetDataAdapter1;

     RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.search);


         firstRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);


         //create and set layout manager for each RecyclerView
         RecyclerView.LayoutManager firstLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

         firstRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstLayoutManager);




         firstRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



         GetDataAdapter1 =  new ArrayList<>();



         JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_VIEWS();


     }
```

**This is my `RecyclerView` `AdapterList` to call the inflate view for the list elements:**

```
public RecyclerViewAdapterList(List<Recipes> getDataAdapter, Context
 context){

         super();
         this.itemList = getDataAdapter;

         this.context = context;
     }


     @Override
     public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


         View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inflate_pagecountry,
 parent, false);
         RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
         return rcv;
     }
     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
         holder.NameCategory.setText(itemList.get(position).getTitle());
         Picasso.with(context).load(itemList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.CategoryLogo);
     }
```

I´m getting but logcat says

15:25:53.476 E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout

Can you help me??

Comment: Edit: Json Parser its working correct, when i use toast, the size its working fine. Another thing its that xml elements declared its fine.

Comment: please check the answer and try

Comment: @RatilalChopda yours answer don't fix my error, don't know where is the error, don't show any RecyclerView.

Comment: what is the size of itemList  in RecyclerViewAdapterList

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)

Comment: @PauloRodrigues please  check my update answer and tell me

Comment: @AesSedai101 lol duplicate in NestedScrollView

Comment: @RatilalChopda don't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.search);

         nsv = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
         firstRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);
         secondRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_2);
         thirdRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_3);
         fourthRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_s);
         fifhtRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_);

         //create and set layout manager for each RecyclerView

        firstRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
         RecyclerView.LayoutManager firstLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
         //RecyclerView.LayoutManager secondLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         //RecyclerView.LayoutManager thirdLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         //RecyclerView.LayoutManager fourthLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         //RecyclerView.LayoutManager fiveLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

         firstRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(firstLayoutManager);
         //secondRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(secondLayoutManager);
         //thirdRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(thirdLayoutManager);
         //fourthRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(fourthLayoutManager);
         //fifhtRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(fiveLayoutManager);




         firstRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         //secondRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         //thirdRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         //fourthRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         //fifhtRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



         GetDataAdapter1 =  new ArrayList<>();
         //GetDataAdapter2 =  new ArrayList<>();
         //GetDataAdapter3 =  new ArrayList<>();
         //GetDataAdapter4 =  new ArrayList<>();
         //GetDataAdapter5 =  new ArrayList<>();


         JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_VIEWS();
         //JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_DONES();
         //JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_LIKES();
         //JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_IDS();
         //JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL_RANDOM();


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Problem is that you are initializing n number of RecyclerView but assigning adapter only for one so you have to assign adapter for all OR comment all other RecyclerView

Comment: comment all views except  firstRecyclerView

Comment: I have declared for Adapter for all and dont work @vikrant arankalle